# how to fix TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter

i just want to add a few buttons to my project so i'm using the `tkinter gui`, but it gives an error:

```
TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed.
```

can someone explain the error and why it is happening.

code:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser
import ctypes
from time import ctime
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import time
import subprocess
from IPython.display import clear_output
import os
from tkinter import *

r = sr.Recognizer()
speak = Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
time_n = ctime()
master = Tk()

def startjarvis(t_run):

    while t_run > 0:

        def record_audio(ask = False):
            with sr.Microphone() as source:
                if ask:
                    print(ask)
                #print there was here 
                audio = r.listen(source)
                voice_data = ''
                try:
                    voice_data = r.recognize_google(audio)
                    #before: print(voice_data)
                except sr.UnknownValueError:
                    print('Did not understand')
                except sr.RequestError:
                    print('speech server down')
                return voice_data

        def respond(voice_data):
            if 'what is your name' in voice_data:
                speak.speak('my name is Jarvis')

            elif 'where do you live' in voice_data:
                speak.speak("I am in Iron Man's suit")

            elif 'Jarvis' in voice_data:
                speak.speak('yes sir')

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            elif "what is the time" in voice_data:
                print(ctime())
                speak.speak(time_n[0:16])

            elif "is the time" in voice_data:
                print(ctime())
                speak.speak(time_n[0:16])

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            elif 'search' in voice_data:
                speak.speak('What do you want to search?')
                search = record_audio('What do you want to search?')
                url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + search
                webbrowser.get().open(url)
                speak.speak('Here is what i found')

            elif 'find location' in voice_data:
                location = record_audio('What is the location?')
                url = 'https://google.nl/maps/place/' + location + '/&amp;'
                webbrowser.get().open(url)
                speak.speak('Here is what i found')

            elif 'what is my location' in voice_data:
                webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+location+now&rlz=1C1GIGM_enIN847IN851&oq=what+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j69i59j69i60l2j69i61j69i60.2695j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8')
                speak.speak('Here is what i found')
                speak.speak('I have placed your location adress on top of your search results')

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            elif 'open Gmail' in voice_data:
                webbrowser.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=rm&ogbl#inbox')

            elif 'open my Google classrooms' in voice_data:
                        webbrowser.open('https://classroom.google.com/')

            elif 'open WhatsApp' in voice_data:
                webbrowser.open('web.whatsapp.com')

            elif 'send a WhatsApp message' in voice_data:
                speak.speak('What is the number of the person?')
                num = record_audio('What is the number of the person?')
                speak.speak('What message do you want to send?')
                search = record_audio('What message do you want to send?')
                speak.speak("please type Time to send the message 24 hour format (hour): ")
                time = int(input("please type Time to send the message 24 hour format (hour): "))
                speak.speak("please type Time to send the message 24 hour format (minute): ")
                time_min = int(input("please type Time to send the message 24 hour format (minute): "))
                url = 'https://web.whatsapp.com'
                pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+91" + num, search, time,time_min)
                time.sleep(10)
                speak.speak("message sent")

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            elif 'dictate' in voice_data:
                speak.speak('Please enter text')
                text = input('Text: ')
                speak.speak(text)

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            elif 'open calculator' in voice_data:
                subprocess.Popen('C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe')

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            elif 'what is the working directory' in voice_data:
                o = os.getcwd()
                print(o)
                speak.speak(f'{o} is the current working directory')

            elif 'what is there in this directory' in voice_data:
                o = os.listdir()
                print(o)
                speak.speak(f'{o} is there in the current working directory')

            elif 'list my files' in voice_data:

                speak.speak('Type the path')
                file_path = input('path: ')

                for folder, sub_folders, files in os.walk(file_path):

                    print(f"Currently looking at {folder}")
                    print('\n')
                    print('\t The subfolders are:')
                    for sub_fold in sub_folders:
                        print(f"\t \t Subfolders: {sub_fold}")

                    print('\n')
                    print("The files are:")
                    for f in files:
                        print(f"\t File: {f}")
                    print('\n')

            #---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            else:
                url = 'https://google.com/search?q=' + voice_data
                webbrowser.open(url)

        print('how can i help you ?')
        speak.speak('how can i help you?')
        voice_data = record_audio()
        respond(voice_data)

        t_run = t_run - 1

        time.sleep(3)

        clear_output()

        time.sleep(2)

        
def times_to_run():
    def run_1():
        startjarvis(1)
        
    def run_2():
        startjarvis(2)
        
    def run_3():
        startjarvis(3)
        
    speak.speak("plaese click the button having number of times you want me to run")
    
    button_1 = Button(master, text="1 Time", command=run_1)
    button_1.pack()
    
    button_2 = Button(master, text="2 Times", command=run_2)
    button_2.pack()
    
    button_3 = Button(master, text="3 Times", command=run_3)
    button_3.pack()

#---------------------#---------------------#-------------#
#last cell below

button = Button(master, text="Start Jarvis", command=times_to_run)

button.pack()

mainloop()
```

i am using `jupyter notebook` and getting the error on the last cell.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: The error means your calling a widget of a window, but you have already destroyed it.

Comment: but i have not destroyed it. i have only added 3 butttons

Comment: Try running the above code on a normal code editor or IDLE

Comment: when i use the code in spyder but it says no module names tkinter,

Comment: Use in some kind of IDLE or IDE, rather than spyder

Comment: if i use sublime:   ```File "E:\Ethans Folder\pyin*********r (**e)\jarv_convert.py", line 14, in <module>
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
  File "c:\users\et***********\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32api'
```

Comment: You have to install these for your anaconda, right?